# Angular 7 | Build --aot fails | Typescript .d.ts declaration files missing from compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, build, angular7

I am currently struggling to build my Angular 7 app (recently updated from v6).

Running `ng build` works **fine**, however, either `ng serve --aot`, `ng build --aot` or `ng build --prod` (which enables aot as well) causes the error below.

The Typescript compiler fails to find my **own** **`.d.ts`** files all located in `src/app/types/`.

I tried to solve the issue by adding the path to these files to the `include` property of the `tsconfig.app.json` file, but it did not work.

Please note that the issue was the same with Angular v6.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/types/data.d.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /xxx/src/app/types/data.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/xxxx/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:767:23)
at plugin.done.then (/xxxx/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Here is the `tsconfig.json` file :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the `tsconfig.app.json` file :

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem :
I checked all the `import` statements of the `.d.ts` files everywhere in my app.
One was wrong (wrong path) , which did not seem to be an issue without the `--aot` flag.
Maybe that will help someone.

Answer (score -2):

Change the `types` key to `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.app.json` since you are specifying a folder instead of specific files.